# invert key and value in dictionary in python3 (the value not unique)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, duplicates, key-value

I know how to simple invert key and value in dictionary when value is unique.
But how to invert when the value is NOT unique.
According requirement, If the value appear more than once, I need use set to make them together.

---

Ex. input `d = {'a':1, 'b':2,'c':1,'d':2}` output `d = {1,{'a','c'},2,{'b','c'}}`

---

I write pretty stupid code show below, but because I only create one set, thus all the value which show more than one times are in that set.

```
def change(d):

    inverted_l = list(map(lambda t:(t[1],t[0]), d.items()))
    store_key = [] #for store the key to check if value appear more than one
    new_d = {}
    x = set()
    for i in range(len(inverted_l)):
        store_key.append(inverted_l[i][0])
    for i in range(len(store_key)):
        if store_key.count(store_key[i])> 1:
            x.add(inverted_l[i][1]) #I think the problem is I need create set
                                    #each time, but I don't know how to do that
            new_d[store_key[i]] = x
        else:
            new_d[store_key[i]] = inverted_l[i][1]
    return new_d

print(sorted(change({'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':1,'d':2}).items()))
```

my wrong output is `[(1, {'c', 'd', 'b', 'a'}), (2, {'c', 'd', 'b', 'a'})]`But I need `[(1, {'a', 'c'}), (2, {'b', 'd'})]`

Added: I try your code, but error occur when I test `print(sorted(invert_dict({'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':1}).items()))`
I want my result is `[(1, {'a', 'c'}), (2, 'b')]`
I am new for python, thank you for your help and time!

```
def invert_dict(d):
    result = {}
    for k in d:
        if d[k] not in result:
            result[d[k]] = set()
        result[d[k]].add(k)
    return {k: d[k] if len(d[k])>1 else d[k].pop() for k in d}



 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "U:\test.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(sorted(invert_dict({'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':1}).items()))
  File "U:\test.py", line 7, in invert_dict
    return {k: d[k] if len(d[k])>1 else d[k].pop() for k in d}
  File "U:\test.py", line 7, in <dictcomp>
    return {k: d[k] if len(d[k])>1 else d[k].pop() for k in d}
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you mean the desired output is not the set

```
d = {1,{'a','c'},2,{'b','c'}}
```

but rather the dictionary

```
d = {1:{'a','c'}, 2:{'b','c'}}
```

Just double checking here:-).

Anyway, I'd do it:

```
import collections

def invert_dict(d):
    result = collections.defaultdict(set)
    for k in d:
        result[d[k]].add(k)
    return dict(result)
```

The `return` could be simplified to `return result` if the `dict` **subclass** `defaultdict` is OK -- it's only necessary to turn it into a `dict` if the spec is very rigorous about that.

I imagine the next step is likely to be an "oops, imports are not allowed" to forbid `collections.defaultdict`, so I'm anticipating that -- in that case, do instead (e.g)

```
def invert_dict(d):
    result = {}
    for k in d:
        if d[k] not in result:
            result[d[k]] = set()
        result[d[k]].add(k)
    return result
```

Added: apparently the latest version is crucial (OP of course "forgot" to add the "no imports" constraint in the first place -- why do they keep **doing** this to me?! would it cost them **anything** to reveal **all** the constraints up front from the start in their Qs?!?!?!!) but a tweak is needed -- singleton sets need to be turned into non-sets of their only element (a horrible, terrible, no-good spec, making the resulting dictionary nearly unusable, and making me strongly wish to have a few sharp words with the no-goodnicks that appear to believe that making disgustingly bad specs improves their teaching, but, that's another rant).

Anyway, best is to add a post-processing step:

```
def invert_dict(d):
    result = {}
    for k in d:
        if d[k] not in result:
            result[d[k]] = set()
        result[d[k]].add(k)
    return {k: d[k] if len(d[k])>1 else d[k].pop() for k in d}
```

Nothing to hard: just "unwinding" singleton sets down to their one item with a `pop`.  (What next -- the belated revelation of yet **another** silly arbitrary constraint such as "no if/else expressions"?!-)

Added (leaving the buggy code above): need to use `result` not `d` in the `return` statement clearly!  I.e the final line must be

```
    return {k: result[k] if len(result[k])>1 else result[k].pop() for k in result}
```

Comment: The answer is correct!But could you please do one more modify? I only want the key add the set when it appear more than one time. Ex. Input:d ={'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':1} Output should d = {(1, {'a', 'c'}), (2, 'b')},and your output is(1, {'a', 'c'}), (2, {'b'}). Thank you! And...import is not allowed is for real! how foresight!

Comment: You can't know in advance whether a `d[k]` will occur again, so, to avoid the horror of type-checking, you'll need a post-processing step -- editing the A to show that.

Comment: Well, the error occur: TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len(). Could you please fix this one....

Comment: In the code I posted, `d[k]` is always a `set`, never an `int`.  So the error you report can't happen **if** you use, **exactly**, my code -- since it can't happen I can't fix it.  Edit your Q to show **exactly** what code you're running and the **full traceback** of the exception you get, and I'll fix your bug (perhaps not tonight as I'm soon off to bed, but maybe if you're very fast, else tomorrow morning).

Comment: I am very appreciate your help. I already modify my question.

Comment: Anyway, I solve the problem by myself. Thank you for your help. I still post your code and error in my problem, that one still has error, hope you find out why it has bug if you have time. Thank you for your help again.

Comment: @vivian, see my last edit -- after carefully building `result`, my `return` statement still erroneously used `d` and ignored `result`!-)